# Does anyone else modify their golf grip on a per shot basis?

Tags: golf

I've found myself modifying my thumb position of my left hand (I swing right) to achieve a fade or a draw.  I think this technically creates a slightly stronger / weaker grip. If I put my thumb on the flag-opposite side of the golf club I find it much easier to drive the ball low and draw it. And the opposite is true for hitting a cut or fade or even flop shots. I literally put the right side of my left thumb on the flag side of the golf club to hit a soft cut or pitch shot.

I also move my left index finger. If I want to drive the ball lower and draw it a little more or even hit a straighter shot I hook my left index finger on the front of the club and push the club into that left index finger to lock it into place.  My left finger is then at least half an inch farther down the shaft than my left thumb.  The reverse is true for a fade.  I move my index finger farther up the shaft. I feel like this has the effect of letting me cup my left wrist easier.

I don't interlock my grip and I overlap my right ring finger on top of my left index finger.

It's definitely helped with my control and consistency while trying to create different types of shots.

Has anyone ever heard of a pro modifying their grip like this on a per shot basis?

Does anyone else do this?

Comment: I had a natural draw for a while when I started golfing regularly which I fixed by making my grip stronger with my right hand (I am a right handed swinger).  I have not heard of players modifying their grip to create draws or fades.  This is done by closing off or opening up the club face.  I will have to try your method next time I'm at the range

Comment: As for the index finger on your left hand... do you not interlock your grip?

Comment: I don't interlock my grip... I'll add it to my question.

Comment: My guess is that your changing of your grip is creating a slightly different swing path or is opening/closing the club face on impact, which is changing the ball flight.  Have you found you are able to control and anticipate the flight of the ball due to your grip?

Comment: I agree with @diggers3...that your changing grip may be creating different shots. I don't do this personally (to change my shot to hit a draw or fade, I change my stance...to hit a high or low shot, I tend to move my stance backward or forward a ball or two and either swing faster or abbreviate my swing). Swing alterations using just the hands is generally frowned upon because of consistency. However, if it works for you, by all means continue what you're doing. The last thing you want to do is ruin a good thing by thinking too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My pro would not advocate changing the grip in terms to produce different shots intentionally as the inconsistency of a changing grip at a low amateur level would outweigh any benefits.

However, we have recently been working on grip and can certainly confirm that certain hand positions can very much prevent a full range of motions which would make it easier/harder to hit certain types of shots (all other things remaining the same).

There are so many variables in the golf swing that I'd rather not introduce more! so unless you're a very good golfer my advice would be to rule one out and try to have a consistent grip.

That said, many people would advocate changing stance or gripping down to produce different shots, so as above, if you're very good and don't suffer any consistency issues then why not!?